# When I applied Armature Modifier, Mesh does not follow the animation

Tags: modifiers, armature, bones

I have a FBX model that has a bone key frame animation.

When I imported it into Blender, it came with a Armature Modifier.

[image]

Then, I applied the modifier. Bones follow the result, but mesh are **separated from bones**.

How can I solve the it?
Any help or tips are greatly appreciated.

---

After a long fighting, finally I solved the problem. I'll post it later.

Comment: In Armature modifier > Object you need to have 'mesh' selected not 'Armature'.

Comment: thanks, but I dont have 'mesh' option  http://i.stack.imgur.com/oBfF9.png

Comment: If you can't see 'mesh' delete 'Armature' first. Or you could post blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I can check this exact case.

Comment: Thanks you so much but I can't due to the project...but thanks again...

Comment: Did you manage to get it working?

Comment: nope, I'm still trying...

Comment: I can't help more without seeing this exact blend file. Sorry for that :(

Answer (score 2):

The answer is fairly simple, don't apply the armature modifier.

Once a modifier is applied, it cannot dynamically change the mesh. Applying a modifier simply takes the current effects of the modifier an applies them permanently to the mesh. This is rarely useful for the armature modifier, as generally you want to keep animating the mesh.

Comment: thank you for your advice. as you said, when I applied the modifier, the current pose applied to the mesh, then the link with armature was removed. only thing I needed was, 1. clear all mesh transforms ( cuz when I load FBX data, it was scaled to 0.01 and 90 deg ), 2. then remove the modifier, after that, link again to [set parent] > [Object keep transform] then [set parent] > [Armature Deform]